# Grouping in REGEXP_SUBSTR() in MYSQL 8.x

Tags: mysql, regexp-substr

I am trying regexp as I know it but doesn't seem to be working in MYSQL v8.0.  I am trying to extract the filename (something.txt) from the some_str variable.  It keeps returning NULL.  Not sure what I am doing wrong in the pattern.

```
set @some_str = "{'A': 1234, 'fname': 'something.txt'}";
select regexp_substr(@some_str, "\\{'\w+':\s+\d+,\s+'\w+':\s+'(.+)'\\}") ;
-- should return:  something.txt
```

Comment: Why you use incorrect quote chars in JSON value?

Comment: Its not JSON.  Its just formatted text.  Can this be done using regexp_substr()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> set @some_str = "{'A': 1234, 'fname': 'something.txt'}";
> SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(REPLACE(@some_str, '''', '"'), '$.fname'));
> ```
>
> ```
>  
> | JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(REPLACE(@some_str, '''', '"'), '$.fname')) |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | something.txt                                                        |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2ad4d148c217721b744e8226cdc0bfb6)*